# Why won't my sidebar media query work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, sidebar

I have a sidebar that slides out 250px using javscript on the desktop view. When it comes to the mobile view I want the sidebar to take up 100% width. I am trying to use Media Queries in Javascript but no matter what changes I make It seems to overwrite my styles I have for my sidebar on the desktop view.

HTML

```
 <nav class="navbar">
  <div id="toggle-btn" class="sidemenu-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <div id="toggle-nav" class="navbar-items animated fadeInLeft delay-1s">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about-me">About</a>
    <a href="#my-skills">Skills</a>
    <a href="#my-portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#contact-me">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
 .navbar {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      background: #141313;
    }

    .navbar .sidemenu-btn {
     font-size: 2.5rem;
     padding: 3rem 0;
     text-align: center;
     margin-left: 1rem;
     cursor: pointer;
     color: #141313;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    }

   .navbar .navbar-items a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1.2rem 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

   .navbar .navbar-items a:hover {
    text-decoration: line-through;
   }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.navbar {
  position: relative;
}


}
```

JS

```
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector("#toggle-btn");
const toggleNav = document.querySelector(".navbar");
const togglenavItems = document.querySelector('.navbar-items');

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", sideMenu);
toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", mediaQuery);


    function sideMenu() {
  if (toggleNav.style.width === "250px") {
    toggleNav.style.width = "0px";
  } else {
    toggleNav.style.width = "250px";
  }

}



function mediaQuery() {
  const x = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)');
  const y = document.querySelector('.navbar');

  if (x.matches && y.style.width === "100%") {
    y.style.width = "0px";

  } else {
    y.style.width = "100%";

  }



}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't set your sidebar to 100% and then with a min-width media query, make it have a max-width of 250px? Just trying to understand your constraints, but that seems like a far easier and less confusing solution.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I just want the sidebar to only be 250px on desktop and 100% width on Mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media queries can do the work. You don't need js for changing the width of the `navbar-items`. See this

```js
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector("#toggle-btn");
const toggleNav = document.querySelector(".navbar");
const togglenavItems = document.querySelector('.navbar-items');

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", sideMenu);

function sideMenu() {
  toggleNav.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;

  }

  .sidemenu-btn {
     font-size: 2.5rem;
     padding: 0;
     text-align: center;
     cursor: pointer;
     color: green;
     position: absolute;
     right: 20px;
     top: 20px;
  }

  .navbar-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    background: #141313;
    transition: all .5s ease;
  }

 .navbar .navbar-items a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1.2rem 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

 .navbar .navbar-items a:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through;
 }


@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-items {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.navbar.open .navbar-items {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div id="toggle-btn" class="sidemenu-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    Toggle
  </div>
  <div id="toggle-nav" class="navbar-items animated fadeInLeft delay-1s">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about-me">About</a>
    <a href="#my-skills">Skills</a>
    <a href="#my-portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#contact-me">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Just adding the media query you can change the width of the element, no need to check in js**

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .navbar-items {
   width: 100%;
 }
}
```

**Adding a `.open` class that will be added on the `.navbar` and will trigger the transition**

```
.navbar.open .navbar-items {
  width: 0;
}
```

**Your js was now simplified**

```
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector("#toggle-btn");
const toggleNav = document.querySelector(".navbar");

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", sideMenu);

function sideMenu() {
  toggleNav.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

Comment: your problem is quite confusing. Is it the code in your js changing the style not being applied ?

Comment: thanks for your help but I just added a new menu just for mobile

Answer (score 0):

This is easier done with CSS to control how it looks on the mobile/desktop, with JS just handling the logic. The following will fix the style discrepancy, and make your JS easier to navigate.

CSS

```
 .navbar{
   width: 250px;
   height: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   background: #141313;
 }     
 .navHidden{
  width: 0px !important;
 }
 /* smaller screen size */
 @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
   .navbar{
     width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navHidden">
```

JS

```
function sideMenu() {
  toggleNav.classList.toggle("navHidden")
}
```

Sidenote

In your included code, the click of your toggle button you will be setting the width of the navbar to **250px**, but then it will be passed through to your next function, which will then swap it to **100%** in **EVERY CASE** regardless of screen size, so the toggle function you have written will never work.

Comment: thanks for your help but I just added a new menu just for mobile.